# Ruby Sketchup-rotate 3d text

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I have found a code to rotate 3d text, 90 degrees.

```
mod = Sketchup.active_model # Open model
ent = mod.entities # All entities in model
sel = mod.selection # Current selection
group = ent.add_group
group.entities.add_3d_text('Right', TextAlignLeft, 'Liberation',  true, false, 60.0, 0.0, 0, true, 1.0)
 tr = Geom::Transformation.rotation(ORIGIN,X_AXIS,90.degrees)
 group.transform!(tr)
```

I want to rotate the text flat, not vertically.

Any variation to the code, does not transform the text the way I want.
Please see the image for clarification, I just want to rotate the image flat.

-

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not test, but I can suppose:

- `X_AXIS` is the red line;
- `Y_AXIS` is the green line;
- `Z_AXIS` is the blue line.

So, you could try this **rotation** `tr = Geom::Transformation.rotation(ORIGIN,Z_AXIS,90.degrees)`.

Since you are rotating around a straight line passing through the origin, you should add also a **translation** along `Y_AXIS` by the 3d_text length.